# How to apply $(this) to single child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am wondering if there is a way to use .children on a parent element and then use $(this) to refer to only the specific child element with an event handler.  Like this:  or see pen here: http://codepen.io/coralsea/pen/JoRrRG

```
 <div class="petals">
    <div class="petal-1">
    </div>
    <div class="petal-2">
    </div>
     <div class="petal-3">
    </div>
    <div class="petal-4">
    </div>
    <div class="petal-5">
    </div>
    <div class="petal-6">
    </div>
    <div class="petal-7">
    </div>
</div>
```

/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.petals').children().draggable()
  $(this).mouseup(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    top: "+=50"
  }, 2000, function() {

  });
});
});
```

I was able to work by adding a class to each child and targeting that, like so: http://codepen.io/coralsea/pen/emdGmo
but it seems being able to do it by targeting the children of the parent would be more efficient.

Comment: As others have pointed out, you can use `$(".petals").children()`, but I don't see anything particularly wrong by targetting the petals directly with `$('.petal')`. What don't you like about that approach?

Comment: Just that the petal class isn't needed for styling so it adds an extra class to the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way of doing it using `stop` event of jQuery Ui:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.petals').children().draggable({
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).animate({
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                top: "+=50"
            }, 2000, function () {
                // Animation complete.
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**[CodePen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emdGBq)**

Comment: @user3209044 if this answer or any other answer here has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. :)

Comment: I would love to, but my reputation isn't good enough yet.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't have to upvote an answer. You just have to accept the answer that solved your problem by clicking on check button below the upvote and downvote button. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can by chaining the commands. (*remove the `$(this)` part*)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.petals')
      .children()
      .draggable()
      .mouseup(function() {
        $(this).animate({
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          top: "+=50"
        }, 2000, function() {
          // Animation complete.
        });
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/WbGZog